# how to render conditionally within the react native stack navigator header?

Tags: react-native, conditional-rendering, stack-navigator

I'm trying to render the headerRight conditionally based on a navigation param. I am currently trying this in the static navigationOptions. Here is my code but nothing is rendering to the screen

```
static navigationOptions = ({navigation}) => ({
headerRight : () => {
  if (navigation.state.params.user.following) {
    return (
        <TouchableOpacity
          onPress={() => this.followUser()}>
          <Icon2 name="ios-person-add-outline" size={35} />
        </TouchableOpacity>
    )}  else {
    return (
          <TouchableOpacity
            onPress={() => this.unfollowUser()}>
            <Icon name="user-times" size={20} />
          </TouchableOpacity>
        )}
    },
})
```

Can this be done or will I need to use a custom header here?

Any help would be hugely appreciated! Thanks!

**Solution:**

remove the anonymous function and implement the conditional syntax recommended by soutot

```
static navigationOptions = ({navigation}) => ({
  headerRight :  navigation.state.params.otherUser.following ?
    ( <TouchableOpacity
         onPress={() => this.followUser()}>
         <Icon2 name="ios-person-add-outline" size={35} />
      </TouchableOpacity> )
    :
    ( <TouchableOpacity
         onPress={() => this.unfollowUser()}>
         <Icon name="user-times" size={20} />
      </TouchableOpacity> )
    })
```

Comment: Which lines shows unexpected token? did you Check if you are passing `user` parameter before triggering navigate?

Comment: sorry , this should have been edited out as it isn't throwing an unexpected token now. Instead it is not rendering anything. Edited to reflect this.

Answer (score 1):

You are using a comma (,) after your 'else' statement. Also you can try something like this

```
return(
navigation.state.params.user.following ?
<TouchableOpacity
  onPress={() => this.followUser()}>
  <Icon2 name="ios-person-add-outline" size={35} />
</TouchableOpacity>
:
<TouchableOpacity
  onPress={() => this.unfollowUser()}>
  <Icon name="user-times" size={20} />
</TouchableOpacity>
);
```

For more info about conditional rendering, check the following docs:
https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/conditional-rendering.html

https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/conditional-rendering.html#inline-if-else-with-conditional-operator

Hope it helps

Comment: This works once I remove the anonymous function and added parenthesis! Thanks!

Comment: can I add condition in onPress? and navigate to different screen conditionally?

Comment: Yes, you can. onPress receives a function. You can add any logic to it as you need. So, in the given example, the condition could be added something like this: ```onPress={() => navigation.state.params.user.following ? this.followUser() : this.unfollowUser()}```. Hope it helps